# doctrine2 : how can I select entities from different repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

In my symfony2/doctrine2 application, users are able to flag elements brought to the admin attention.

I need to retrieve all flagged elements (they implement a VoteInterface).

I'm trying without success to do the following, but it's not working because I need to select at least one root entity. If I select one root entity, I've got a memory allocation error.

Anyway, I'm not even sure this is the right way to go. How can I select all elements associated to votes ? Of course I can build one querybuilder for every entity type but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish here, I'd like one single query builder.

```
public function getFlagsQueryBuilder()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('u, c, p')
        ->leftJoin('v.user', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('v.comment', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('v.post', 'p')
        ->groupBy('u, c, p')
        ->addSelect('u, c, p')
        ->where('v.value = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, 0)
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having memory issues, it may be because your are loading too many rows in memory at the same time.

From the Doctrine docs:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing

It will let you Iterate through your results without having memory issues. It will load rows when needed.

You could also use these methods to query a limited number of rows:

Query::setMaxResults($maxResults)

Query::setFirstResult($offset)

If you are planning on getting COUNT, SUM, AVG or any other aggregate functions on a column, I suggest you make a query to get those instead of aggregation information from your iteration. It will be faster with a query.

I hope this helps out

Comment: thanks but I'm more trying to figure out how to write this query correctly to fetch the different entities in one time.